# How to scrape online data from within a span tag

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get the value R1200 as defined by the "one Way drop off surcharge" description.I have tried using various methods of getting the element but have not been able to get the information. The idea is, I want to fetch the 1200 value and paste it into a cell in excel. I am new to both vba and html.

I have already managed to get the scraping tool to navigate to the specific webpage in question by clicking the relevant inputs, below is the sample code I have tried to get the value.

This is the HTML where the value resides:

```
<div class="itinerary-column">
<div class="optional-extras">
<h4>
Price Summary
</h4>
<ul class="clearfix extras">

<li>
Document admin fee<span>R 99.00</span>
</li>
<li>
Vehicle Rental <span>R 1575.00</span>
</li>
<li>
<!--This is part of the temporary solution to show the oneway surcharge-->
One Way Drop Off Surcharge<span>R 1200.00</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="total-price clearfix">
Total

<span>
R
<span class="value">
2874.00
</span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="deposit">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="deposit-req">
Deposit required
<span>(Not included in total)</span>
</div>
<div class="value">
R <span>4170.20</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="excess-message">
Rate incl 200 KMS free per day.Extra @ ZAR2.12 p k
</div>

</div>
```

This is the code I have tried to get the value:

```
'Cells(r, 3).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("optional-extras").innerHTML
'Cells(r, 2).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("optional-extras").innerText
Cells(r, 6).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("optional-extras").innerHTML
Cells(r, 6).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("clearfix extras").innerHTML
'Cells(r, 4).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("clearfix extras").innerText
'Cells(r, 5).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("clearfix extras").innerHTML
'Cells(r, 6).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("ul").Item(25).innerText   'yields something
```

Comment: did you try `getElementByClassName("clearfix extras").getElementsByClassTagName("span").Items(3).innerText` - first `getElement...` is without `s` in word `Element`

Comment: do you means scraping tags from remote web pages?

Comment: @furas - Sadly it returned nothing,

Comment: @Netlog - I am scraping values from within tags on a website. Specifically from within the 'span' tags

Comment: it was only example that you can use more complex method to get item. Using `xpath` (probably `getElementsByXPath`) you could create even more complex method.

Comment: Use **XPath** to get to your class. Then use something like **GetElementdbyTagName** to get to your list elements. Loop through until you find the caption you want

Comment: I tried Cells(r, 2).Value = appIE.document.getElementByxpath("/clearfix extras/span").innerText, no success, not entirely sure how to use this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many elements have the compound classes of clearfix extras? As a general selector the following is correct: .clearfix.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span

Used as follows:

```
Debug.Print appIE.document.querySelector(".clearfix.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
```

However, if your item is not in the first element with that compound class then the css selector will need expanding to account for that

OP says 3 needs to be 2 for case in hand

Comment: Check how many items on  the page have the compound class first. Also, ensure a wait before hand in case value is dynamically populated.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I changed the number 3 to 2 as my data lay in the third instance of 'Clearfix extras'. It seems to work. I honestly don't know why its working but I guess I have work to do regarding query selectors. Thanks again.

Comment: you are most welcome. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors  and https://flukeout.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

if you want scrape inside of a tag from a remote (or local!) web page just use below free DOM parser
 [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/)
there is a good manual and samples, its so simple to use ...

Comment: Thank you Netlog, unfortunately I work on a secure server and I'm not allowed to access that link.